# Error: `unable to connect to github.com` while building DXA HTML design

Tags: dxa

I am playing with the DXA HTML design on https://github.com/sdl/dxa-html-design/tree/release/1.2 When running `bower install` (as per instructions in this [README](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-html-design/blob/release/1.2/design/README.md)) I get an error message

> Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github
>   .com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable to
>   connect to git hub.com: github.com[0: 192.30.252.128]: errno=No such
>   file or directory

[image]

When trying repeatedly sometimes the same command fails on anther repo, i.e. `git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that my workstation can nicely access GitHub, but not on SSH. So like the error message says the requests to `git://github.com` fail. The solution is to use HTTPS instead.

Tell GIT to connect over HTTPS instead of SSH:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669091/bower-install-using-only-https

Comment: typical issue when you work in an office with a paranoid IT department, they have no idea that SSH is actually just as safe as SSL, and simply block all they don't know or think doesn't matter.